# Is it permissible to cache/reuse Thread.GetNamedSlot between threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-local-storage

The [Thread.GetNamedDataSlot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getnameddataslot(v=vs.110).aspx) method acquires a slot name that can be used with `Thread.SetData`.

Can the result of the `GetNamedDataSlot` function be cached (and reused across all threads) or should it be invoked in/for every thread?

The documentation does not explicitly say it "shouldn't" be re-used although it does not say it can be either. Furthermore, the example shows GetNamedDataSlot used at every GetData/SetData site; even within the same thread.

For example (note that `BarSlot` slot is not created/assigned on all specific threads that the TLS is accessed);

```
public Foo {
    private static LocalStorageDataSlot BarSlot = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("foo_bar");

    public static void SetMethodCalledFromManyThreads(string awesome) {
        Thread.SetData(BarSlot, awesome);
    }

    public static void ReadMethodCalledFromManyThreads() {
        Console.WriteLine("Data:" + Thread.GetData(BarSlot));
    }
}
```

---

I asks this question in relationship to *code structure*; any micro performance gains, if any, are a freebie. Any critical issues or performance degradation with the reuse make it not a viable option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the result of the `GetNamedDataSlot` function be cached (and reused across all threads) or should it be invoked in/for every thread?

Unfortunately, the documentation isn't 100% clear on this point. Some interesting passages include…

From [Thread.GetNamedDataSlot Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getnameddataslot(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Data slots are unique per thread. No other thread (not even a child thread) can get that data

And from [LocalDataStoreSlot Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.localdatastoreslot(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The data slots are unique per thread or context; their values are not shared between the thread or context objects

At best, these make clear that each thread gets its own copy of the data. But the passages can be read to mean either that the `LocalDataStoreSlot` itself is per-thread, or simply the data to which it refers is per-thread. I believe it's the latter, but I can't point to a specific MSDN page that says so.

So, we can look at [the implementation details](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,7f1b90e450f74800):

There is a single slot manager per process, which is used to maintain all of the per-thread slots. A `LocalDataStoreSlot` returned in one thread can be passed to another thread and used there, and it would be owned by the same manager, and use the same slot index (because the slot table is also per-process). It also happens that the [`Thread.SetData()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,3761084311d52c44) method will implicitly create the thread-local data store for that slot if it doesn't already exist.

The `Thread.GetData()` method simply returns `null` if you haven't already set a value or the thread-local data store hasn't been created. So, the behavior of `GetData()` remains consistent whether or not you have called `SetData()` in that thread already.

Since the slots are managed at a process-level basis, you can reuse the `LocalDataStoreSlot` values across threads. Once allocated, the slot is used up for all threads, and the data stored for that slot will be unique for each thread. Sharing the `LocalDataStoreSlot` value across threads shares the *slot*, but even for a single slot, you get thread-local storage for each thread.

Indeed, looking at it this way, the implementation you show would be the *desirable* way to use this API. After all, it's an alternative to `[ThreadStatic]`, and the only way to ensure a different `LocalDataStoreSlot` value for each thread in your code would be either to use `[ThreadStatic]` (which if you wanted to use, you should have just used for the data itself), or to maintain your own dictionary of `LocalDataStoreSlot` values, indexed presumably by `Thread.ManagedThreadId`.

Personally, I'd just use `[ThreadStatic]`. MSDN even recommends this, and it has IMHO clearer semantics. But if you want to use `LocalDataStoreSlot`, it seems to me that the implementation you have is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the great writeup and explanation from the implementation side of things! I definitely prefer ThreadStatic/ThreadLocal.. this is for 'interoperability' with external code.